# calling a script before the managed bootstrapper application is loaded

Tags: windows, wix, wix3.5, bootstrapper, burn

I am new to wxs and I want to run a script which sets certain registries,right before my managed bootstrapper application is loaded. I haven't found any article which talks about the same.I thought by using custom actions it would solve my requirement,but i am able to see the output of this script only when it is added in the Product.wxs of the induvidual msi packages and not in the Bundle.wxs.But adding it is too late by the time it executes.I want my script to be the very first script on double clicking my bootstrapper exe. Is this possible?Please help

```
 <CustomAction Id="CreateFileCA" BinaryKey="hello.vbs" Execute="immediate" VBScriptCall='' Impersonate="no" Return="check"/>
      <Binary Id="hello.vbs" SourceFile="D:\hello.vbs"/>
      <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action='CreateFileCA' Before='LaunchConditions'>NOT Installed</Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Why? It's a bad practice to start changing the user's machine before the user has any chance to agree to anything.

Comment: We want to enable the SafeDllSearch registry because sometimes when the exe is launched from downloads folder,its picking up some system dlls from the current working directory. we are looking for a solution to prevent the dll hijacking problem before bootstrapper appln is loaded.

Comment: WiX v3.10.4, v3.11.2, and v3.14 should not be vulnerable to this problem. If you are using an older version, you need to upgrade. If you are using one of those versions, then please email security@firegiant.com with details. They will respond and resolve without exposing the WiX Toolset community to 0-day attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomAction` can only be used in an MSI. v3 was silently ignoring it when it was used in a bundle, but v4 will give a warning.

In v3, it's not possible to run anything before the BootstrapperApplication. The only way to run your code is through the BA.

In v4, there is a new concept of BundleExtension that gets loaded before the BA but it should not be used in this way. Modifications to the user's machine should only be done by packages during Apply.